# How to serialize a PHP SplHeap for storing into memcached

Tags: php, memcached, serializable, spl

I am facing a problem in which I would like to store a SplHeap (or any other kinds of Spl heap-like objects such as SplPriorityQueue, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap) into a location of my Memcached in order to use them later.

I noticed that doing it without serialization, would cause losing the data stored in the heap.

Any suggestion for this matter? or how to serialize a PHP SplHeap?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The SPL comes with a Serializable Interface. So your SplHeap class should implement this interface like the following code.

```
class MySplHeap extends SplMinHeap implements Serializable {

    public function compare(ArrayObject $a, ArrayObject $b) {
        return ($b->member - $a->member);
    }

    public function serialize() {
        $objects = new ArrayObject();
        $heap = clone $this;

        foreach ($heap as $node) {
            $objects[] = $node;
        }

        return serialize($objects);
    }

    public function unserialize($serializedData) {
        if (!is_object($serializedData) && gettype($serializedData) == 'object') {
            $serializedData = serialize($serializedData);
        }

        $objects = unserialize($serializedData);

        foreach ($objects as $node) {
            $this->insert($node);
        }
    }
```

}

The Serializable interface implements the serialize() and unserialize() methods. So you can declare special functionality in your splheap class.